# Using registers and inline assembly (ARM)

Tags: c, arm, inline-assembly

I have a small program that I'm trying to use to identify the CPU frequency programmatically.

My program is structured as follows:

- Set an alarm
- Increment register in a `while(1)` loop
- Compute speed upon `SIGALRM`

Initially, I was using

```
register unsigned int cycles asm("r6");  
...  
while(1)
    cycles++;
```

Upon using objdump, I noticed that this actually translated to the following:

```
9aa0:       e1a03006        mov     r3, r6  
9aa4:       e2833001        add     r3, r3, #1  
9aa8:       e1a06003        mov     r6, r3  
9aac:       eafffffb        b       9aa0 <estimate_from_cycles+0x1cc>
```

Since I wasn't sure why this translated to 3 instructions, I tried using inline assembly instead:

```
register unsigned int cycles asm("r6");  
...  
while(1)
    asm("add r6, r6, #1);
```

This translated to:

```
9aa0:       e2866001        add     r6, r6, #1  
9aa4:       eafffffd        b       9aa0 <estimate_from_cycles+0x1cc>
```

- Why did the previous implementation translate to 3 instructions?
- On the ARM platform, `b <label>` instruction takes 3 cycles. Subtract operations on ARM however, use only 1 cycle.

  - Is there any way I can subtract from PC register?
  - Is subtract even allowed on PC?
  - Is there any other way to reduce the number of cycles required to implement the same logic?

**edit:** I'm using CodeSourcery's arm-none-linux-gnueabi- toolchain with no optimizations

Comment: This is a very bad method. Your process is going to be context-swapped off the CPU many times to handle interrupts / allow other processes to run.

Comment: Forgive me if my OS principles are incorrect, but wouldn't my register state be saved and restored upon context switching from and to my process?

Comment: He's saying that you wouldn't get an accurate measurement. Going back on topic, what optimization flags are you using?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The implementation translated to 3 instructions very likely because you didn't enable any optimisations.

However, from a quick test, it looks like you'll have to write inline assembly anyway because when I compile the following using `-O3 -fomit-frame-pointer`

```
void test(void) {
        register unsigned int cycles asm("r6");
        while(1) cycles++;
}
```

the routine simply got optimised down to

```
00000000 <test>:
   0:   eafffffe    b   0 <test>
```

Even adding `volatile` is useless since the compiler knows for sure that writing to a CPU register will definitely not have any side effects (unlike memory) so it's fair for it to get optimised out.

Answering your other questions,

- Is there any way I can subtract from PC register?
- Is subtract even allowed on PC?

Yes, certainly. But I'm not sure if that still costs one cycle.

- Is there any other way to reduce the number of cycles required to implement the same logic?

As a side note, your logic won't give very accurate results because your process may be switched out between when you start and finish measuring.

You're expecting:

```
<                    your process                     >
|<---------------your alarm duration----------------->|
```

When, it's probably more like (where `|` is a context switch):

```
<your process> | <other processes ...> | <your process>
|<---------------your alarm duration----------------->|
```

Comment: http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man2/timer_create.2.html tells me that CLOCK_PROCESS_CPUTIME_ID should solve the timer issues..or am I misunderstanding something? I'm currently not using any optimizations

Comment: If you're not using any optimisations, that would make sense. Hmmm, I wasn't aware of `CLOCK_PROCESS_CPUTIME_ID` so I'm not sure if it does what you think it does.